# Showing Tutorial Screen only on first launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        MenuViewController *menu=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home"];
        MainNavigationController *navController=[[MainNavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:menu];
        self.window.rootViewController=navController;
    }
    else
    {
        LaunchViewController *vc=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tutorial"];
        self.window.rootViewController=vc;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I'm using the following code in the app delegate above to show Launchviewcontroller only on the first launch but it's not working for some reason!

Comment: The NSUserDefaults logic is correct, it's something else like the name of the nib, step through with the debugger and or log the state of your key

Comment: @CliffRibaudo Do you think it may have something to do with storyboard and how I've set LaunchViewController as the initialviewcontroller?

Comment: Define "not working". What actually happens? Delete the app and reinstall. Does that help? Step through the code with the debugger and verify which path the code takes.

Comment: Why don't you do this check in your initial view controller?

Comment: @rmaddy Not working as in every time I quit the application and launch it again, LaunchViewController always shows up!

Comment: @rmaddy The weird thing now is that instead of **MainNavigationController *navController=[[MainNavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:menu];** when I do **UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:menu];** it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I would do, I will reset the simulator by chossing the iOS Simulator from the menu first. Then, choose **Reset Content and Setting**. It will clear up all the **NSUserDefaults** data. Therefore, I can know more about what the problem is.

The `- application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method will only be called when you launch it. It means that it's not called when you just transit from the background to the foreground.

I think you probably need to understand the process. And hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but I've tried this multiple times! The weird thing now is that instead of **MainNavigationController *navController=[[MainNavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:menu];** when I do **UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:menu];** it works!

Comment: I am so sorry that I did not see the connection between your comment and the question you posted. Perhaps next time, you can give us more info so that we can address the problem more accurately. Anyway, it's good as long as it works. But, it might happen again if you don't understand that.

Comment: No! I haven't solved the problem yet. I want to use MainNavigationController which I have created myself instead of UINavigationController! It's just that when I use the generic navigation controller, it works some how.

Comment: So, can you tell us what you see and what's your expectation?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but sometime I cannot add Bool value to NSUserDefaults, let try with NSString (exam: HasLaunchedOnce = @"0"/@"1")

Comment: Thanks but NSUserDefaults is working perfectly fine!